RISC V : I don't understand what the GNU assembler does with labels in the .data segment
I am making my own risc V core as a personal project using the RV32I ISA, I am using a Harvard memory architecture meaning I have a program memory that starts at address 0x0 and a separate data memory that also starts at address 0x0.
I am using the risc V gnu toolchain.
Using labels in the .data segment and addressing this data with it's labels in the .text segment, makes the assembler produce a binary that doesn't make sense to me, the following is my example.
Here is the first code I want to present:
.data

.byte 0x01
.byte 0x02

.text

lb x1, 1(x0)

So, here all seems fine when I simulate my core, I get x1=0x02 at the end of the execution as it loads the byte at byte address 0x1 into x1. This is what I assume is the correct behavior (is my assumption correct ?).
Now, when I write the following code I would expect the behavior to be exactly the same as before:
.data

.byte 0x01
my_label: .byte 0x02

.text

lb x1, my_label

However it isn't, I get x1=0x01.
I have assembled both codes using the command riscv32-unknown-elf-as -march=rv32i -o program.o program.s. In the first code, I see that the assembler translated lb x1, 1(x0) one to one, however in the second code,lb x1, my_label turned into:
auipc x1, 0
lb x1, 0(x1)

This will obviously load the byte address 0x0 which is not what I want.
I really don't understand this behavior, I am guessing that this might be the assembler that is perhaps not made for the Harvard architecture but I would like to know if anyone has an explanation for this and how to fix my issue properly.
I am planning to compile some bigger codes and execute them on my core so I must make sure that everything works.
Thanks in advance for your responses and have a great day/evening !

The assembler has added a relocation entry that you likely forgot to dump out. It is handled by the linker that I assume you have not run.

Thank you @Jester !!!!
You led me down a rabbit hole where I learned a lot about linkers, before that, I thought linkers where only used to link multiple files but actually it is much more important than I thought, linking memories and handling references and such.
After playing around with some tools I used the linker and a linker script to generate the executable and now the label is correctly replaced by 1(x0).
Thanks again !

The assembler has expanded your lb x1,my_label pseudo instruction into a pc-relative access using 2 instructions.
Both the auipc and the lb need to work together to access that data location, auipc supplying (the upper) 20 bits and lb supplying (the lower) 12, allowing for an up to 32-bit pc-relative access.  Both the auipc and the lb need to be adjusted for the offset from/difference between wherever the data item winds up and the location of wherever the auipc winds up in the final program.
Since the assembler doesn't necessarily know both of those (let alone either, depending on where data is being located), it simply puts 0 for the offset in auipc and also 0 for the offset in lb, and defers the proper adjustment to the linker by producing a relocation item for each of those instructions in the object file.  (If for some reason, the linker cannot resolve the offset, it would defer the relocation to the runtime loader, but that should not happen here.)
It is common for linkers, in processing relocations, to sum values to the immediate of an existing instruction rather than fully replacing the immediate (this is useful in certain scenarios and harmless in others) — thus, an offset of 0 is commonly found in the machine code generated into the object file, when relocations are involved.

For fun let's note that the lb instruction has a 12-bit immediate, but that the hardware will interpret the immediate as signed value, so if the 12th bit happens to be set, the hardware will treat that as a negative value, and this has the effect of as if subtracting one from the immediate value used in the auipc.  The relocation record forms are aware of this so when the final pc-relative offset is known (i.e. to the linker) and that 12th bit is set, it will add 1 to the immediate summed into the auipc instruction, mitigating subtraction effect by the sign extension in the lb instruction.

Also for fun, let's note that unlike MIPS, the RISC V assembler does not reserve any of the valuable CPU registers for the assembler/compiler to use for pseudo instruction expansion, and so while it allows lb x1,my_label as a pseudo instruction, it does not support the dual in store instruction, sb x1,my_label — unless you supply an additional register for it to use, for the RARS assembler the syntax would be sb x1,my_label,x2, for example, which will store x1 into the global variable using x2 as an intermediate temporary register.  For the load version it simply reuses the register being loaded into since that will be wiped out by the ultimate load operation anyway, but with the store instruction there's no known to be available register to use in a similar manner, so RARS solution is that you tell it an available register.

If you need to both load and store a global variable using pc-relative access, we can share one auipc for both a load and a store, but it gets harder to express, RARS for example, doesn't support this as far as I know.  However, a decent compiler can do this (share one auipc for multiple loads and stores to the same memory location).
The easiest thing for an assembler programmer to do is to use the la pseudo instruction to compute the address of the global variable into a spare register, and then use an offset of 0 to deference that register's value, though that will cost one instruction (auipc followed by addi).
Yet still, there are pseudo function like %hi() and %lo() provided by some (but not all) assemblers that can be used save that one instruction (the addi).

In another programming model, the access to the global variable can be absolute instead of pc relative.  Then the pseudo instruction expansion would substitute auipc with lui, though otherwise much of the discussion remains the same as for the pc-relative access.

And yet in still another programming model using the $gp register to access data, if you have linker relaxation, and the global data item lands within the first 8192 of the data section, the expansion might be reduced to a single instruction, an access using the $gp register as the base.  (Without linker relaxation or failing to land in the first 8192 of data, will result in a 2 instruction $gp-using sequence.)

Thanks a lot Erik for the very valuable insight !
Indeed, because of my lack of knowledge, I have overlooked the linker and as such, the label reference couldn't be made.
After using a linker and using a linker script specifying both .text and .data segments, it now works perfectly.
Indeed, given the fact that the data entries were at addresses 0x0 and 0x1, the linker simply replaced "lb x1, label" with "lb x1, 1(x0)" which is exactly what you you said regarding linker relaxation.
Also your comment on "sb" is very valuable as I have yet to test this instruction yet.
Thanks again !

So the fix may be quite obvious to some but I have simply overlooked the linker. I first recompiled the risc V toolchain to include the correct mabi (may not have been necessary). 
I am now compiling using:
riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-as -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -o "$OBJ_FILE" "$ASM_FILE"
riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-ld -T "$LINKER_SCRIPT" -m elf32lriscv -o "$EXECUTABLE" "$OBJ_FILE"

The linker script for my particular memory configuration (where both the .data and .text segment should start at addresses 0x0) is:
MEMORY {
    program_memory : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 1K
    data_memory    : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 1K
}

SECTIONS {
    .text : {*(.text)} > program_memory

    /*the data memory should be after the program memory in the executable*/
    .data : {*(.data)} > data_memory AT > program_memory 

    .bss  : {*(.bss) } > data_memory
}

I also had to slightly modify my asm file so that the linker knew the entry point of the program:
.data

.byte 0x01         
my_label: .byte 0x02

.text
.globl _start

_start:
    lb x1, my_label

With these changes, the final binary translates "lb x1,label" into "lb x1, 1(x0)" which is exactly the result I expected to have in the beginning.
Also, as a note, after the compilation I have done some post processing on the binary to include it in my fpga simulation, this was done using "riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-objcopy", "xxd" and a python script. 
If someone want to know more details, don't hesitate to ask me. 
A big thanks to everyone in this thread that helped me and provided me with insight on my issue !
